# Django: Push Data to iPhone and Android Devices without APNS or GCM

Tags: android, ios, iphone, django, sockets

Is there any way I can push data to an iPhone & Android device without using APNS or GCM? APNS and GCM are unreliable. I used to use APNS and GCM for in app messaging. Whenever a user in my app would send a message to another user, a push notification was sent to the recipient. Upon delivery, it would make the app reload the chat view so that the recipient would see the latest message that was sent.

I don't actually send the message through the push notification, I just use the push notification as a signal to reload so that the app can grab the new message objects from the Gunicorn/Django server.

This worked for a while but I soon discovered that pushes weren't always delivered and that APNS and GCM are unreliable. I've done some research about sockets and socket.io and using them with Django. But they are all web related. I'm looking for something that is geared towards communication between mobile devices and my Django/ Gunicorn server. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: socket is a option and easy workaround is to hit a service after 20 second....most of the times receiving  a notification after 10 sec (median case if you hit service after every 20 sec) does not really harm...

Comment: Unless you are develeoping a iOS enterprise app, I don't think you can push to iOS devices without APN(if you exclude pure web apps).

Comment: APNS and GCM are very reliable. Your issue may be caused by your networkor or bugs in the  libaray/code you used in both servers and devides.